# Best way to connect multiple data sources produced by java program

Tags: java, excel, network-programming, connection

I have created a Java program that tracks the usage of items on the floor. It uses SQL to grab items based on the user input. All this information is stored in an excel file on the local machine, it is updated every time they enter new information. This program runs on about 20 computers and I'm looking for ideas to connect all these excel documents. All the machines are on the same network so I have considered making the program on every computer put the excel doc into a shared folder, then just adding all the data into one excel file from there. The output does not have to be in excel, I could change that.

So basically I have a program that collects data from multiple users on different computers and I want to have all this data in the same place. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Use a database and aggregate it.

Comment: If all machines are running on same network, just use database instead excel files

Comment: Do you have any resources on a good way to set up a database for this?

Comment: You could use a jdbc connection that utilizes a macro, or you can make a custom interface to it.   Otherwise, I know that excel has good support for Microsoft Access, however it's not the best database to use.  You'd have to have the database in a place where all the clients can talk to it.  You might have to rethink your client/server contract as well if they're changing records concurrently.

Comment: They will be entering information at the same time, so the database will have to handle that, this is my main problem. They will want to periodically check all the information, so my first thought was to just combine all the excel docs at the time they want to check. But I'm sure this is not the best way to go about it. I have not created my own database before so this is new to me.